# Storing a value from SQL database to a variable

Tags: c#, sql, database, variables

I tried this code to extract a single value from my database and store it in a variable. But it extracts the value `Supplier ID` instead of `Quantity`.

```
string query3 = "SELECT Quantity FROM Supplier WHERE [Supplier ID]='"+supplierid+"'";
SqlCommand cmd3 = new SqlCommand(query3, con);
con.Open();
string temporaryquantity = cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
MessageBox.Show(temporaryquantity);
```

**How can I extract `Quantity` instead of `Supplier ID`?**

Comment: Note your code has sql-injection

Comment: ... and you can find out more about avoiding SQL injection in C# [here](http://bobby-tables.com/adodotnet).

Comment: Can you post your database structure -- what fields are in the `Supplier` table? Your SQL as written should return the value in the `Quantity` field, but it seems a little strange to have the `Quantity` in the `Supplier` table -- doesn't the `Quantity` change depending on the order and item, even though the `Supplier` remains the same?

Comment: I don't see any syntax problem with your query. Did you test it with any DBMS tool (e.g. SQL Server Management Studio) to ensure that the query is correct?

Comment: `SELECT Quantity` - extracts data for Quantity column. Instead, change it to "Supplier ID" column name. Check this one please - https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_select.asp.

Comment: Yeah, thank you. It had been a problem with my variable naming. I created cmd3 and executed cmd. That was a huge mistake.

Comment: Thanks anyway, for letting me know about about SQL injection and all the other related things...

Answer (score 3):

Your query will return the Quantity field... *if you execute it*. Your variable naming is unfortunate - you're creating `cmd3` and executing `cmd`.

Execute `cmd3`, and your result will be as expected.

Comment: Thanks a lot, for spotting my huge mistake. I corrected it and now it works fine. Thanks again.